# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import (2021)

Tags: numpy

I am doing a Finance Portfolio optimization using Python on Jupyter Notebook. But it is not working for some reason.  I have already installed PyPortfolioOpt package successfully. Here are the codes:

```
from pypfopt.efficient_frontier import EfficientFrontier
from pypfopt import risk_models
from pypfopt import expected_returns
```

This is the result:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I have looked at the other answers on Stack Overflow related to this. I've already uninstall and reinstall numpy many times. But still shows the error message. Can anyone help me on this problem please?? Thank you.

Comment: which version of bumpy do you have installed? `pip list | grep numpy`

Comment: It was `numpy 1.20.3` I have installed.